# Sorting DESC results in "Invalid column name" error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, sql-scripts

I have a table `MOVIE` with a column `Desc` which stands for description.

I tried to sort by this column:

```
SELECT 
    * ,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Desc] ASC) AS RowData
FROM 
    (SELECT
         UID,
         Title,
         [Desc] AS '[Desc]'
     FROM 
         MOVIE) AS RowTable
```

I get this error

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
> Invalid column name 'Desc'

Anyone able to help?

Thank you.

Comment: change '[Desc]' to  'Desc' or [Desc]

Comment: or in your first select use  [[Desc]]

Comment: And this is why we avoid using the names of keywords as names of our columns.

Comment: `[Desc] AS '[Desc]'` Here is your problem. Firstly, don't use keywords as names EVER - avoid the complications you create for yourself! Here you changed the column name to include the brackets. Why? There is NO reason to use an alias here at all as you don't do anything useful with it. Just remove it and your query will work. But better yet is to not use keywords as names.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT 
    * ,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Desc] ASC) AS RowData
FROM 
(
    SELECT
        UID,
        Title,
        [Desc] AS [Desc]
    FROM 
        MOVIE
) As RowTable
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is change The column name of **Desc**. either write description or another name.

beacuse IN SQL

> The **DESC** command is used to sort the data returned in descending
> order